# How to use lifecycle on Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, neo4j-php-ogm

I need to save the date of creation and update of all the nodes of my graph. I do not know how to use the lifecycle. Or is that I have to do the process manually?

Comment: You can do it manually in Cypher, you can create a trigger (see APOC), you can create an event handler, ... (and I don't know the possible way with neo4j-php-ogm)

Comment: Can you confirm you are using the PHP OGM, it is possible with event listeners, once you confirm I can create an answer with an example code

Comment: Yes, I'm using [neo4j-php-ogm](https://packagist.org/packages/graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm)

Comment: Cool, I already answered such question actually. Check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138492/graphaware-neo4j-php-ogm-event-listeners

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen thank you very much for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138492/graphaware-neo4j-php-ogm-event-listeners)